# Set DIV visibility from a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to show and hide a div based on a condition. This time I am not using any function since I thought it would be better as simple as possible.

I am trying to show and hide 2 DIVs based on a "status" of the user (`$new`). I don't know if it's possible to assign a PHP value to a JavaScript variable and the best way to do it ...

"var" is supposed to get the value of "$new".

Javascript:

```js
<script> 
var var = $new;      
if (var != 1) {
  document.getElementById("subjectr").style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById("subjectr").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```html
<center>
  <div id="subjectr" value="<?php echo "$new"?>" style="display: none">
    <a href="" id="ifYes" style="background-color: green; border: 2px solid #44db2c; display: none;" method=POST; class="btn btn-info">COORDINADOR</a>
  </div> 
</center>
```

If you know a better way to do it, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: `<center>` tag is obsolete

Comment: Javascript won't like your var being called "var". Change it to "myvar" or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need JS, simply echo or wrap the desired HTML into an *if `$new` is `true`* right on the server-side

#### Using PHP

```
<?php if ($new) { ?>

<div>Content for new users</div>

<?php } ?>
```

---

#### Using CSS (and PHP)

```
<div class="<?= $new ? '' : 'isHidden' ?>">Content for new users</div>
```

```
.isHidden { display: none; } /* Add this class to CSS file */
```

The above might come handy if at some point, by using JavaScript you want to toggle the visibility of such element using `.classList.toggle('isHidden')` or jQuery's `.toggleClass('isHidden')`

---

#### Using JavaScript (and PHP)

If you really want to pass your PHP variable to JavaScript:

```
<div id="subjectr">Content for new users</div>

<script>
var isNew = <?php echo json_encode($new); ?>;
document.getElementById("subjectr").style.display = isNew ? "block" : "none";
</script>
<!-- The above goes right before the closing </body> tag. -->
```

---

PS:

- The `<center>` tag might work in some browsers but it's long time obsolete. Use CSS instead.
- The `value` is an invalid HTML5 attribute for `div` Element. Use `data-value` instead.
- What's doing the `method=POST;` on an `<a>` tag?
- `var var` is a syntax Error in JavaScript, `var` being a **reserved word**. Use a more descriptive `var isNew` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using javascript, you could use PHP to influence the display style of your div by using a ternary to decide whether it is `none` or `block`:

```
<center>
  <div id="subjectr" value="<?=$new?>" style="display: <?=$new != 1 ? 'block' : 'none'?>">
    <a href="" id="ifYes" style="background-color: green; border: 2px solid #44db2c; display: none;" method="POST" class="btn btn-info">COORDINADOR</a>
  </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

For first, you should avoid to use `var` as a variable in your JS code, since it's an reserved key.

For your problem, revise your JS code:

```
<script> 

var cond = document.getElementById('subjectr').getAttribute('value');   

if (cond != 1) {
  document.getElementById("subjectr").style.display = "block";

}
else {
  document.getElementById("subjectr").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

You can get attribute result using `getAttribute` method in javascript, or `attr` method in jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

A javascript variable can get the value of a PHP variable like so (assuming the PHP var is an integer):

```
var myvar = <?=$new?>;
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you tag this as a PHP and a CSS issue, I think our mobile function is pretty near. This is our CSS "shownot" class:

```
.shownot { display: none !important; }
```

After, we use to hide certain cols on device mobiles, in your case the "$new" var:

```
<?php
$new = isMobile() ? 'shownot' : '' ;
?>
```

Finally, use as class whenever you need

```
 <div id="subjectr" class="<?php echo $new;?>">
    <a href="" id="ifYes" style="background-color: green; border: 2px solid #44db2c; display: none;" method=POST; class="btn btn-info">COORDINADOR</a>
 </div>
```